# (geo)pandas: _ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.75 GiB for an array with shape (57, 13533946) and data type object

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, memory, geopandas

I've been working with moderately-sized geographic data sets in geopandas, and I've started experiencing a host of strange memory-related problems with code that has run without any trouble plenty of times before.

For example, the most recent one is for a function that concatenates some data sets:

```
global spine
spine = pd.concat([parcels2021, parcels2017, parcels2006_merged, parcels2010_merged], ignore_index=True)\
.drop_duplicates(subset=['PARCEL_SPI'], keep='first')
```

This gives the following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.75 GiB for an array with shape (57, 13533946) and data type object.
```

This has worked many times before, including this morning. I had to rerun the operation due to some changes in the data, but nothing would have changed structurally with my system as I have only been doing mundane data cleaning tasks since it last worked.

I have seen responses to similar questions where people have been working with huge datasets that eats up the computer's entire memory and the solution has been to break it up into smaller chunks, but this is not a particularly large data set for 16gb RAM - and, as I keep mentioning, it has worked fine until now.

Interestingly, the 5.75 GiB falls to 85.8 MiB and the shape changes to (3, 3750715) after trying the function again, but goes back to the original if run one more time. It seems like this is part of the problem because the original spine object that was created in the past would be an array of (73, approx. 4300000), so I don't know why it's trying to make such a large array - also strangely, a lot of the data processing I've done today has been removing columns and there ended up being exactly 57 of them. I have no idea where it's getting this number from but it seems too specific to be a coincidence.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but it looks like you have an extra `[` in your code. 

`pd.concat([parcels2021, parcels2017, parcels2006_merged, parcels2010_merged], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Ah yes that was actually just a typo as I wrote this out on a different computer - well spotted!

Comment: Are there a lot of duplicated `PARCEL_SPI` present in each dataset, e.g. `parcels2021`? Might be worth trying to drop duplicates in each dataset before the `pd.concat`

Comment: Nah it's mostly that the later years contain a lot of the previous years e.g. parcels2021 contains the majority of the ones in parcels2017 and so they can only be dropped when they're concatenated

Comment: Probably not the most optimized solution but if you need something going perhaps you could try removing duplicates before the concat: `pd.concat([parcels2021, parcels2017[~parcels2017['PARCEL_SPI'].isin(parcels2021['PARCEL_SPI'])], parcels2006_merged[~parcels2006_merged['PARCEL_SPI'].isin(parcels2021['PARCEL_SPI'])], parcels2010_merged[~parcels2010_merged['PARCEL_SPI'].isin(parcels2021['PARCEL_SPI'])]], ignore_index=True)`